# Add square brackets in json using python

Tags: python, json

I've a json as below. I just wanted to add a part of square brackets on the key 'activities'. but am new to this python coding, so am not getting any approach to insert square brackets for a particular component in JSON using python.

```
{
    "name": "CopyPipeline-rdc",
    "properties": {
        "end": "2017-02-14T00:00:00Z",
        "start": "2017-02-14T00:00:00Z",
        "activities": {
            "name": "CopyActivity-0",
            "type": "Copy",
            "input": {
                "name": "InputDataset-rdc"
            },
            "output": {
                "name": "OutputDataset-rdc"
            },
            "policy": {
                "retry": 0,
                "timeout": "00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionpriorityorder": "OldestFirst"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "interval": "1",
                "frequency": "Day"
            },
            "typeproperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource",
                    "recursive": false
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "BlobSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                }
            }
        },
        "expiration": "15.00:00:00",
        "description": "''",
        "pipelinemode": "OneTime"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this a  blunder.
`data = json.loads(query_result)
for activity in data['name']:
 for key in list(response.keys()):
  activity[key] = name[key]`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply 'add' square brackets to a portion of a JSON output. The square bracket is used to denote an array, list, or other enumerable sequence of objects.

In order to achieve something like what you're requesting, you'll have to modify the `activities` property (or dictionary entry) to a list, tuple or other appropriate sequence type.

Sample code:

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = {"activities": [{"name": "CopyActivity-0",
...                        "type": "Copy",
...                        "input": {"name": "InputDataset-rdc"}
...                        }]    # note that we used [] to create an array
...       }
>>> print json.dumps(obj, indent=2)
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "input": {
        "name": "InputDataset-rdc"
      },
      "type": "Copy",
      "name": "CopyActivity-0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for .. but how will I extract this activities part alone? and if you don't mind, can you please help with teh significance of indent and dumps module of json?

Comment: This is the point where I pose the same question Nils Werner asked in [a comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/72507085): _"what have you tried so far?"_. You haven't provided information on how the data was obtained. Neither have you described what you have done so far. The combination of these two makes it practically impossible for anyone to help you except to give you pointers based on theories they have.

Comment: actually I have used a query to fetch the data and use JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY to build it as a json file. since the query is too long, i'm not able to paste it. any other way i can show the query here.

Comment: After the query result is fetched:

            cursor.execute(query,{ 'objectName': objectName ,'dataFactory' :dataFactory})
]
        query_result=cursor.fetchall()
        query_result=ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(query_result))
        query_result=str(query_result).replace('\\','').replace('[','').replace(']','') .replace('"{"','{"').replace('"}"','"}').replace('}"}','}}').replace('\'{','{').replace('}\'','}')
        #j = json.dumps(query_result)
        objects_file = objectName+'.json'
        f = open(objects_file,'w')
        f.write(query_result)

Comment: cursor.execute(query,{ 'objectName': objectName ,'dataFactory' :dataFactory})

        query_result=cursor.fetchall()
        query_result=ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(query_result))
        query_result=str(query_result).replace('\\','').replace('[','').replace(']','') .replace('"{"','{"').replace('"}"','"}').replace('}"}','}}').replace('\'{','{').replace('}\'','}')
        #j = json.dumps(query_result)
        objects_file = objectName+'.json'
        f = open(objects_file,'w')
        f.write(query_result)

Comment: @Arjun: please move the updates in your question. It's the best way to make a clear, well written post. Doing so will also increase your chances of getting an answer that works.